# apache rewritten querystring triggering internal server error (500)

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, internal-server-error

Can someone please help me with the following:

First, I have an index page living in a directory called 2012. The index page $_GETs a parameter titled 'slug'. Example:

http://www.mydomain.com/2012/index.php?slug=alaska-state-4a

I would like for a rewritten URL to look like the following:

http://www.mydomain.com/2012/alaska-state-4a

I cannot seem to get the rewrite rules below to work properly. They are of course separate attempts and both are not in the .htaccess file at the same time. They keep triggering internal server errors.

```
    RewriteRule ^2012/([^/]*)$ /2012/index.php?slug=$1 [QSA, L]
    RewriteRule ^2012/([^/]*)$ /2012/index.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with both of these statements and help modify them so that they function as I've intended?

NOTES: Aside from my 'village of the banned' denied ips, the only other rules above the rewrite attempts in my .htaccess file are:

```
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Im not the expert but is there anything on your error logs to do with the request? It may help answer your question!